# Docker container is not reachable when generated with docker-compose

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

im testing docker 19.03 on an ubuntu 20.04 server

when i start a nginx container with

```
docker run --name nginx2 -p 80:80 --rm nginx
```

everything is fine : the webserver can be accessed with the ip of the Ubuntu Server

but when i start the container with docker-compose

```
services:
  nginxProxy:
    container_name: nginxProxy
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

The webserver is not responding

---

i solved the issue : it has to do with netplan, found the solution here https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/924

To complete the description of my setup:

- i installed first docker with the package docker.io (from ubuntu) and hat the exposed problem.
- I now reinstalled my Ubuntu 20.04 from scratch and installed docker with the package docker-ce (from docker) and could not connect to any container. The docker0 bridge was down.

my netplan was

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      mainif:
        match:
          name: '*'
        dhcp4: yes
```

i changed it to (a described in the source, having 2 nic with eno1 and eno2)

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
      mainif:
        match:
          name: 'en*'
        dhcp4: yes
```

now everything is fine

Comment: Please add the output of `docker-compose up` to your question.

Comment: Creating network "proxynet_default" with the default driver<br/>
    Creating nginxProxy ... done<br/>
    Attaching to nginxProxy<br/>
    nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration<br/>
    nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/<br/>
    nginxProxy    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf<br/>
   nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up`

Comment: run it with docker-compose up -d

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a version option to the top of the `docker-compose.yml`. I just tried it on Ubuntu 20.04 and it opened the default Nginx landing page. Here's the file I used:

```
version: "3"
services:
  nginxProxy:
    container_name: nginxProxy
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

Also, the output you pasted sounds like it's working as expected. I don't know where you're running the server, but it might also be related to some firewall issues or misconfiguration. As per @Rezwan's suggestion, in order not to follow what's happening in real time, add the `-d` option:

`docker-compose up -d`

and try to access the web server by just typing its IP address in browser. Here's the log output from my setup:

```
Creating nginxProxy ... done
Attaching to nginxProxy
nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginxProxy    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginxProxy    | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginxProxy    | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginxProxy    | ip.add.re.ss- - [04/Dec/2020:22:28:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 612 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Comment: sorry, i only copied partially my docker-compose.yaml, i already have version : "3" in the file.